# open and bring focus to geocode search box

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox

I just started using mapbox. I'd like to know if I can open (via javascript) the search box field there. Additionally, can I set focus to it?

[image]

Comment: Show some code please

Answer (score 0):

Add `autofocus` to the input element

Answer (score 0):

```
<input autofocus type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
keepOpen: true
```

Comment: Where did you put this setting? I tried it in the map object declaration and in the geocoder object but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

To set the focus, you need to find the class name and set focus() property to that class. See below code:

```
// Add focus to the geocoder
  document.querySelectorAll('.mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder--input').forEach((item: any) => {
    item.focus();
  });
```